# How to get the trigger keywords of a query rule through PowerShell

Tags: search, powershell, keywordquery, enterprise-keywords

I'm attempting to export all query rules for a provided URL to a csv file via PowerShell.  I have this working about 80%, the last piece I need is to find the keywords or terms that actually trigger the query rule.  Through Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Rules.QueryRuleManager I can collect the query rule title, any promoted results, publication info (start date, end date, etc) but I can't seem to return the triggering keywords.  The only related property I can seem to find is "QueryConditions" which tells me the rule is fired via keyword but not what they are.  Is there another reference or something else I am missing?

Any help or insight appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the `QueryCondition` items from QueryConditions (which really is ends up being an `IEnumerable<QueryCondition>`) to `KeywordCondition` objects. From what I can tell, the collection is just a bunch of objects that report as the superclass, and you need to cast them to the specific class to actually access the properties that make them unique. I say this because the inheritance hierarchy of a KeywordCondition is:

```
System.Object
  Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Rules.QueryCondition
    Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Rules.KeywordCondition
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.rules.keywordcondition%28v=office.15%29.aspx for information about the inheritance.

The `KeywordCondition` type has a `Terms` property (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.rules.keywordcondition_properties%28v=office.15%29.aspx for a full list) which is an `IEnumberable<String>` and which should list all the strings that trigger the query condition.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange! If you could give an example, it would improve your answer a lot. We try to discourage answers that are primarily just links as even MSDN links have been know to go disappear.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I moved more information into the post so it should stand on its own without needing to read the links.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!  I was finally able to get this figured out and access the terms by using '$rule.QueryConditions.Terms' even though msdn does not list Terms as a property of the QueryConditions class.